# Struts 2 fails to initialize Dispatcher in executable war - Embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, struts2, embedded-tomcat-8, xwork

I'm migrating a webapp from JBoss to Embedded Tomcat. It works on intellij but when I run the `war` file with `java -jar myapplication.war` it shows the following error. After googling I couldn't find any solution. This problem seems like I have two `struts2-core` jars or some dependencies conflicting but I have just one jar.

Sample project [here](https://github.com/GeorgeBarbosa/spring-boot-struts2).

**Error:**

```
 2017-12-11 10:58:24.527 ERROR 10296 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher   : Dispatcher initialization failed
 
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to load configuration.
         at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70) ~[xwork-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:978) ~[struts2-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446) ~[struts2-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490) ~[struts2-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74) [struts2-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.servlet.StrutsServlet.init(StrutsServlet.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:795) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
 Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory
         at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:247) ~[xwork-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102) ~[struts2-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:240) ~[xwork-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67) ~[xwork-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         ... 23 common frames omitted
 Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name struts has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/C:/workspaces/workspace/pessoal/spring-boot-struts2/target/spring-boot-struts2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.34.jar!/struts-default.xml:65:72
         at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:231) ~[xwork-core-2.3.34.jar!/:2.3.34]
         ... 26 common frames omitted
```

**My relevant stuffs:**

**StrutsServlet:**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "*.do" })
public class SBSStrutsServlet extends StrutsServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4919365268043339311L;

}
```

**Application.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring"/>

    <package name="sbs" namespace="/sbs" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="welcome" class="com.gbarbosa.sbs.controller.HelloWorldAction">
            <result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`WEB-INF\lib`:**

```
asm-3.3.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
classmate-1.3.3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-lang3-3.2.jar
ecj-4.5.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.26-incubating.jar
hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar
jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
jackson-core-2.8.8.jar
jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
log4j-api-2.7.jar
log4j-core-2.8.2.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
logback-core-1.1.11.jar
ognl-3.0.21.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
snakeyaml-1.17.jar
spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
struts2-core-2.3.34.jar
struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.34.jar
tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar
tomcat-embed-el-8.5.14.jar
tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.9.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
xwork-core-2.3.34.jar
```

**WAR structure final:**

```
META-INF
org
sbs
WEB-INF
```

I'm really stuck on this and on IntelliJ It works fine. I have no idea why Struts has already created a bean called `struts` and of type `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory`.

Please, someone has any idea?

Comment: It's created by the dispatcher when the framework is started. If it fails, then you have something wrong with the configuration or dependencies.

Comment: I believe It's something in my packing build on maven because when I build as an executable jar Struts starts well and the action is called but I can't use an executable jar because It doesn't serve JSP pages, It just find the JSP pages if I put my src\main\webapp folder in the same directory of my jar file.

Comment: You can't, because you missing them.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. I would like to build as an executable war. Isn't it possible?

Comment: How did you build an executable war?

Comment: I'm using the spring-boot-maven-plugin to repackage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Although of It looks like a duplicate jar issue It is not. The problem there is: tomcat container is providing two different paths to the same file. Different prefix paths **jar:file:/** and **jar:war:file:/**.

> Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name spring has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/C:/target/spring-boot-struts2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.34.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:29:132 - bean - jar:war:file:/C:/target/spring-boot-struts2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war*/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.34.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:29:132

To solve that I just changed the struts2-core and struts2-spring-plugin scope from compile to provided. The spring-boot-maven-plugin put these files under WEB-INF/lib-provided then when I run with java -jar myapplication.war these jars are provided in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To make executable jar or war from the maven project, you should use

```xml
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <executable>true</executable>
            <classifier>boot</classifier>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

which allows you repackage war file to make it bootable. You can find more about [Spring Boot Maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) on this page or on the [Usage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html) page.

> #### 66.2 Packaging executable jar and war files
>
> Once `spring-boot-maven-plugin` has been included in your `pom.xml` it
>   will automatically attempt to rewrite archives to make them executable
>   using the `spring-boot:repackage` goal. You should configure your
>   project to build a **jar** or **war** (as appropriate) using the usual
>   packaging element:
>
> ```xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>     <!-- ... -->
>     <packaging>jar</packaging>
>     <!-- ... -->
> </project>
> ```
>
> Your existing archive will be enhanced by Spring Boot during the
>   `package` phase. The main class that you want to launch can either be
>   specified using a configuration option, or by adding a `Main-Class`
>   attribute to the manifest in the usual way. If you don’t specify a
>   main class the plugin will search for a class with a 
>   `public static void main(String[] args)` method.
>
> To build and run a project artifact, you can type the following:
>
> ```xml
> $ mvn package
> $ java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> ```

Comment: Thanks Roman C! It's exactly what I have been doing but It didn't work properly.

Comment: No you didn't. It didn't work for you because you didn't read this answer properly.